# Swig : Java packaging give violation access exception

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

I've been struggling during all the day to fix a problem :

- When I create a Java wrapper by Swig to my C/C++ application without specifying a package I don't get any access error while runing my Java program and everything works fine.
- BUT, when I do : `swig -c++ -java -package my.package.name -outdir my/pachage/name` , My JVM crash and gives me the following error trace :

  A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006eaf26c0,
>   pid=10348, tid=5500  JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
>   (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13) Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
>   Problematic frame: V  [jvm.dll+0x1226c0]
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

I absolutely need to make my code in a package, and not leave it in "default package".

I'm using JDK 7 (51u), 64-bits.

My DLLs are successfuly loaded in both cases ( with/without packaging ) using `System.loadLibrary`.

I will be so grateful for any help! thank u!

Comment: How are you running the application (Command-line? Double-click?)

Comment: What is your OS? Are you using VM?

Comment: You might find this easier to do with [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna)

Comment: Is it a type or error that your package path is misspelled in -outdir? Have you tried to compare generated .cpp files with some diff utility? Is difference is truly only in package names or is there something else? And final question: that is the point of crash in java/swig generated file, you can find some hints from the stack.